# Possibility of the result of length of two n-bits length integer

Tags: algorithms

I have known from my calculation and [Maximum bits of two n-bits ingeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789949/if-two-n-bit-numbers-are-multiplied-then-the-result-will-be-maximum-how-bit-long) that the maximum bits of two n-bits integer is 2n bits.

I need to handcraft a RSA and I know that the modulus which is the key length needs to be 1024 bits to 2048 bits. From the result above, I know that the maximum bits of two n-bits integer is 2n bits, **but there is possibility that the length of the result is only 2n-1 bits.**

So I would like to know the possibility of the result of length of two n-bits length integer when

1. both two integer is greater than $2^{n-2}$
2. both two integer is in $[1,2^{n-1}-1]$

A proof will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not what you asked, but here is an easy way to achieve what you want:

First, generate random pairs of 16-bit integers $p_0$ and $q_0$ (each $\ge 2^{15}$), until you get a pair that satisfies

$$p_0\cdot q_0\ge 2^{31}$$

Then generate two $n$-bit primes $p$ and $q$ with most significant 16 bits $p_0$ and $q_0$, respectively. These will satisfy $pq>2^{n-1}$, which is what you want.

The probability that such a randomly generated pair satisfies $p_0\cdot q_0\ge 2^{31}$ is approximately $2(1-\ln 2)\approx 0.614$, so the first stage shouldn't take long.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, and it helps. If it is possible, I would like to know why it is approximately 2(1-ln2) for this case? I still want some mathematical proof here.

Comment: @KarlHan: divide $p_0$ and $q_0$ by $2^{16}$, and you have a point $(p_0,q_0)$ in the top right quarter of a unit square. Now you want the area of the region where $p_0\cdot q+0\ge\frac12$, divided by the area of that top right quarter. This is a simple exercise in integration.

Comment: That should be $p_0\cdot q_0\ge\frac12$.